# Rails 6: How can I use `button_to` in a presenter class?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a presenter:

```rb
class PresentedOrderService
  include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers

  attr_reader :service, :order
  delegate :date, to: :service

  def initialize(service, order)
    @service = service
    @order = order
  end

  def order?
    service.date == order.delivery_date
  end

  def confirmation_text
    'Click ok to confirm your order.'
  end
end
```

I have a view which shows a button conditionally:

```
<% if service.order? %>
  <div class="badge badge-success">Your order is booked for this date</div>
<% else %>
  <%= button_to service.button_text,
      arrange_delivery_path(
          id: service.order.id,
          date: service.date,
        ),
      data: {
              confirm: service.confirmation_text
            }
  %>
<% end %>
```

As a refactoring step, I want to move the button into the presenter:

```
<% if service.order? %>
  <div class="badge badge-success">Your order is booked for this date</div>
<% else %>
  <%= service.button %>
<% end %>
```

```rb
class PresentedOrderService
#...
  def button
    helpers.button_to(
      button_text,
      arrange_delivery_path(
        id: order.id,
        date: date,
      ),
      data: { confirm: confirmation_text }
    )
  end
```

However, this doesn't work. I get this error error in the console:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `protect_against_forgery?' for nil:NilClass):
    18:               <% if service.order? %>
    19:                 <div class="badge badge-success">Your order is booked for this date</div>
    20:               <% else %>
    21:                 <%= service.button
    22:                 %>
    23:               <% end %>
    24:             </div>

app/controllers/orders_controller.rb:21:in `button'
app/views/orders/edit.html.erb:21
```

I can see that the problem comes from using the `button_to` method because I see the same error when I change my code to:

```rb
  def button
    helpers.button_to 'Home', Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.root_path
  end
```

I'm not sure what the error is referring to when it says `nil:NilClass`. Where does that come from?

What steps do I need to take to enable `button_to` to work in the presenter. Is it possible?

**Update**

Here's the controller:

```rb
class OrdersController < ApplicationController
  def edit
    @order = Order.find(params[:id])
    @services = ServiceDate.all.map { |service| PresentedOrderService.new(service, @order) }
  end

  def update
    if @order.update(delivery_date: params[:date])
      flash[:success] = 'Your delivery has been booked'
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      flash.now[:warning] = 'Error. Please try again or contact support'
      render 'edit'
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems unrelated to button. `protect_against_forgery?` is a method that enable security for CSRF attacks. Usually, this error appears when using Rails as API mode, because Controllers does not extend from ApplicationController but ActionController. Check if this is your case.

Comment: My controller inherits `ApplicationController`. If that's the case should my presenter class extend something?

Comment: Can you add the ApplicationController code to the answer?

Comment: I've added it to the bottom of the original post.

Comment: Try this: 

in application_controller.rb

`class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
end`

Comment: Still results in the same error. Even after restarting the Rails server.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have more info. Maybe because Rails 6 is only in release candidate could have some bugs. Try looking your issue in github/rails or report it if you don't see it.